# Google Apps Email cannot receive emails from other domains on our server. Plesk

Tags: email, g-suite, gmail, mx-record

Not sure if this is the right spot to post this, but I have setup Google Apps email for one of our domains.

I can receive and send messages from domains that are not hosted on the same server as the one we just setup Apps for.

For example lets say I setup Google Apps for test.com.  Example.com is also hosted on the same server.
test.com will receive emails through google apps from a.com, b.com, c.com, etc. that are hosted on other servers.
test.com will not get emails from example.com that is hosted on the same server.

It is a plesk sever.  For some reason it will intercept the emails instead of letting them go to google.  I can see them through the plesk webmail.
Apps will receive emails from domains not hosted on our server.

The MX records are exactly as specified in the docs.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify OS / MTA / Plesk version, but practically it is always the same.
You need to disable the mail service for the domain which handles mail via Google.

External mail servers will check the MX record of the domain to figure out where to send mail to and see the records point to Google - and it will work correctly.

If this mail is also originating from your server (example.com) it will first check locally if itself is not the mail server (assuming Linux / qmail: `/var/qmail/control/virtualdomains`).
It finds that test.com is configured there and delivers it locally.
If you disable the mail service on this domain it should be removed from the qmail configuration and it will correctly delivered to Google.